# Will I get rejected from getting a US tourist visa a young person with no travel history

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

**What are my chances of being denied for a USA travel visa as a first-time traveler.**

I am trying to travel to the US for a week to visit a friend I met online a few years ago.

I am a 19-year-old South African, and I recently got a new commission-based sales job.
I want to apply for a tourist visa to the US to visit a friend of mine I met online a few years ago.

Unfortunately, I have no travel history on my new passport.
The only country that I have ever visited is Lesotho (which does not require a visa from South Africans).

I had a 1-year contract job before my current job.
This allowed me to save up some money for the trip.
Along with that, my mom and my friend will help me with my expenses for the trip.

Based on this info, is there a good chance that I may get approved for a visa?

P.S. I am not yet studying

Comment: From these details, there is a very good chance that your visa will be rejected.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country Your profile doesn’t tick any of the eligibility boxes, plus SA to US is a very long way to travel for just a week’s stay. Your question may be closed as opinion-based, however you really do not stand any chance of getting a US visa IMHO

Comment: @Traveller - Do you believe that "ties to my home country" is the main thing that i have to worry about here?

or are ther more areas I have to worry about?

Comment: @Sizwe Yes, in essence, because without strong ties it will be nigh on impossible to overcome the US’ automatic legal presumption of immigrant intent

Comment: Besides the lack of ties I also see the lack of enough money and that you get help from two people to bring up the money is not helpful.

Comment: Also, "visiting a friend you meet online" sounds very much as a scam. Or, in case you are female and they are male, it may look as if you expect to remain with him.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/b1-b2-us-tourist-visa-refusal