# Once I get my US B-2 tourist visa interview, do they approve the visa at the interview?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

Do they approve my B-2 visa right after the visa interview at the embassy? At the interview? Or when do they approve? How do I know?

Comment: Others who actually know will probably give you a precise answer, but it’s my understanding that they don’t give the result during the interview (probably to avoid issues with people who are refused).

Comment: This question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/b1-b2-us-tourist-visa-refusal indicates that refusals are also advised at the interview

Comment: U.S officials states essentially smth like "There are only two possible outcomes of the visa interview. Either approval or refusal". So the answer to your question is "Yes, you will immediately know the interview result". It is possible to fall under "administrative check" (which theoretically could take forever). That means REFUSAL, but if the decision is positive you will automatically get a waiver for that refusal (along with your visa).

Answer (score 6):

I can only speak from direct experience. Therefor this is not a given and might change from person to person and/or the country where the visa appointment is held. It is up to the officer to make a final decision at any time/any location.

Back in January 2020 I applied for the B2 visa in The Netherland and I also did the interview in The Netherlands (U.S. Consulate General Amsterdam). The officer did the interview and immediately after that he notified me that my visa got approved and that they would mail the passport in a few days.

Comment: This is accurate also from my end in Vienna, Austria. I had an interview at the US Consular section and the officer told me right after the interview that I was approved and my passport would be ready in a few days.

Answer (score 4):

When we (family of 6) got our B1-B2 visas, we had the interview and the officer that conducted the interview told us immediately at the end of the interview that we were approved for our visas and that we'd receive our visa stamped passports returned to us within (if I recall correctly) a week.

So yes, we were made aware at the interview, but did not receive the passports/visas at that time, they were sent back to us by UPS.

And as this may differ depending on location, our interviews were at the US consulate in Tijuana, Mexico, in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this today because I was curious (my wife is currently interviewing as we speak). Regarding denials, I do know of a close friend of ours who got denied in person at her interview because she forgot to bring her university diploma. This was important because due to the university changing its name since her graduation, she effectively had zero proof of where she went to school.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the decision would be communicated to you at the interview.

One notable exception is that when your file requires additional administrative processing. A [refusal under section 221(g)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/administrative-processing-information.html) is issued at the interview in that case. But this is not a final refusal of your visa application. Usually, the consular official would also advise you if you need to submit any additional documents.

This may happen for various reasons, notably for nationals of countries of concern (e.g. China, Iran, Russia) where additional security assessments are needed sometimes, particularly if the applicant is an employee of the government or state-owned enterprise, or studies in areas of concern (e.g. nuclear technology, biology, chemistry, artificial intelligence).